# Dynamically created nested Div's not rendering JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of JavaScript which is meant to be dynamically creating a nested set of Div's in my application. The parent Div is being created just fine, however the inner Div is not rendering at all.

Any help would be great!

JavaScript:

```
function createWindow()
{
    var note_window = document.createElement("div");
    note_window.setAttribute("id", "note_window");
    note_window.setAttribute("class", "notification-window");
    note_window.style.visibility = 'visible';

    var title = document.createElement("div");
    title.setAttribute("id", "title");
    title.setAttribute("class", "col-md-12");
    title.innerHTML = "Notifications";
    note_window.appendChild(title);

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    navbar.appendChild(note_window);
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="note_window" class="notification-window" style="visibility: visible;">
    Text
</div>
```

Desired HTML:

```
<div id="note_window" class="notification-window" style="visibility: visible;">
    Text
    <div id="title" class="col-md-12">
        More Text
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your help guys, I have partly answered my own question...

Further down in my code there is another function which edits the contents of note_window.

```
    if (document.getElementById("note_window") == null)
    {
        createWindow();
        if (getNotifications() == null) {
            note_window.innerHTML = "Text"
        }
    }
```

When I comment out the code for setting the innerHTML, both Div's render correctly... Now the question is... Why!?

Comment: Your code is working for me http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/YXBJxv?editors=101

Comment: works for me too. http://jsfiddle.net/qmfyp5k4/

Comment: works for me too https://jsfiddle.net/f9dprvkt/

Comment: How are you verifying this is the rendered HTML?

Comment: I am just checking the element explorer in developer tools using Chrome.

Comment: Code above won't work unless you already have an element with an id= "navbar" in the markup. This JS line fails if element doesn't exist `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");`

Comment: the navbar is specified in the HTML mark up of the page... The odd thing is that the outer div note_window is displayed perfectly, just not the inner.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your requirement. You can refer here https://jsfiddle.net/f9dprvkt/2/ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```js
var note_window;
var title;
function createWindow()
{
    note_window = document.createElement("div");
    note_window.setAttribute("id", "note_window");
    note_window.setAttribute("class", "notification-window");
    note_window.style.visibility = 'visible';
    //note_window.innerHTML = "Text";

    title = document.createElement("div");
    title.setAttribute("id", "title");
    title.setAttribute("class", "col-md-12");
    title.innerHTML = "Notifications";
    note_window.appendChild(title);

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    navbar.appendChild(note_window);
}

function getNotifications() {
  return null;
}

if (document.getElementById("note_window") == null)
    {
        createWindow();
        if (getNotifications() == null) {
          var text = document.createTextNode('Text');
          title.parentNode.insertBefore(text, title);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">some content</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting, I am specifying the innerHTML for the note_window element in a different part of the application. Let me test your above code and see

Comment: Perfect! This works! In practice I'm actually now using two inner DIVs as I want one of them to display a dynamic list so I will need to use the innerHTML to generate the list. The Text there is just to be used when there is no data to populate the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or this (in case everything needs to be created dynamically via JavaScript):

http://plnkr.co/edit/3pNmY3UnqbgZWpSFVH66?p=preview

```
function createWindow()
    {
        var note_window = document.createElement("div");
        var title = document.createElement("div");
        var navbar = document.createElement("div");

        note_window.setAttribute("id", "note_window");
        note_window.setAttribute("class", "notification-window");
        note_window.style.visibility = 'visible';

        title.setAttribute("id", "title");
        title.setAttribute("class", "col-md-12");
        title.innerHTML = "Notifications";

        navbar.setAttribute("id", "navbar");
        note_window.appendChild(title);
        navbar.appendChild(note_window);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(note_window);
    }
```

And the HTML markup

```
<body onload="createWindow()"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working for me, I've just modified the text to match to your example.  I have a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yye4dsqm/3/

```
function createWindow() {
  var note_window = document.createElement("div");
  note_window.setAttribute("id", "note_window"); 
  note_window.setAttribute("class", "notification-window");
  note_window.style.visibility = 'visible';
  note_window.innerHTML = 'Text';
  var title = document.createElement("div");
  title.setAttribute("id", "title");
  title.setAttribute("class", "col-md-12");
  title.innerHTML = "More Text";
  note_window.appendChild(title);

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  navbar.appendChild(note_window);
}

createWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems so simple now...

In my edit I mention that I am setting the innerHTML of the parent DIV, this is then overriding the entire child DIV with text. Setting a break point after the initial creation shows the elements rendered correctly.

I wasn't seeing it before as I was only looking at the elements after the call had been made to set the innerHTML.

Thanks guys!

Outside perspective always helps! :)